# Getting snippets in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, search-engine, nutch

I'm running Solr + Nutch and need to get a snippet of each result. I tried setting `hl` to `true` in the query URL but I still get the same XML result (without snippets). Any ideas on how to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the fields that you want highlight results returned for by passing field names to the `hl.fl` parameter in your query. Please see [HighlightingParameters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters) on the Solr Wiki for more details and examples.

Comment: Thanks. This may be silly but what are "fields"? I want to get a Google-style snippet - a sentence that summarizes the document, or even the sentence(s) where matches were found. Haven't tried it yet (no access to the Solr environment at the moment) but what would hl.fl='*' return?

Comment: That would return a highlight snippet for all fields in your index. Doing that would be a bad idea for performance reasons. A field is essentially an attribute of the indexed item in Solr. Once you access to your environment it will make more sense. Would recommend that you look at the Solr Wiki http://apache.wiki.org/solr and the tutorial on the Solr page http://lucene.apache.org/solr